# Is it possible to use fabric.contrib.files.append() on a local file?

Tags: fabric

Trying to append() to a local file using Fabric.

I'd like to use

```
append('/etc/ssh_config', ['\n\nHost', '\n\tIdentityFile', '\n\User'])
```

But unfortunately it only tries on remote files

Attempting to wrap append within local(), like so:

```
local(append('/etc/ssh_config', ['\n\nHost', '\n\tIdentityFile', '\n\User']))
```

...fails miserably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't believe so.

If you look at the [source code for append](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/contrib/files.py) it loops through the lines, escapes any regexes in the line and if the line is not already present in file based on a `egrep` check, it does a `echo line >> file`
It should be possible to wrap all this up a triple-quoted shell snippet that can then be passed to `local`

Comment: I think you're right - I ended up doing a local("echo '\n\nHost \nIdentityFile \nUser' | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh_config"). Thank you! Will mark you as answer when site allows me to :)